# How to reset picture back from artistic effect in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, shapes, effect

I am trying to figure out something. I have a picture in my Excel file. Whenever I click on it I want it to become grayscale so I use the following vba code:

```
Sheets("Dashboard-3").Shapes("ReportsIcon").Fill.PictureEffects.Insert msoEffectPencilGrayscale
```

And it works  perfectly fine. But then I want it to get back to its original color and formatting when I click again (Which is the `Reset Picture` button in Excel). unfortunately recording Macro doesnt get that. I use `msoEffectNone`, `msoEffectTypeNone`, but doesnt work. Also searched a lot but seems no one has tried to reset the artistic effects back. Does anyone have a clue what should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to set a different effect, you have to remove it with `Delete` from the list of PictureEffects that are assigned to the picture. The following Sub shows how to toggle it (if it is present, it is removed, else applied)

```
Sub toggleEfect(sh As Shape, efecttype As Long)
    Dim fe As PictureEffect, found As Boolean
    For Each fe In sh.Fill.PictureEffects
        If fe.Type = efecttype Then
            fe.Delete
            found = True
        End If
    Next
    If Not found Then sh.Fill.PictureEffects.Insert efecttype
End Sub
```

You can call it with

```
toggleEfect Sheets("Dashboard-3").Shapes("ReportsIcon"), msoEffectPencilGrayscale
```